# Is it okay for data model class to hold multiple Lists for an abstract object & its children

Tags: java, list, oop, subclassing, datamodel

I'm in the midst of testing my Java knowledge, and my OOP skills. The project I'm working on right now has a singleton data model class, which uses an ArrayList data structure.

```
public class FundingRequestData {
    private ArrayList<FundingRequest> fundingRequests;

    private static FundingRequestData instance = new FundingRequestData();

    public static FundingRequestData getInstance() { return instance; }

    public FundingRequestData() {
        this.fundingRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public FundingRequestData(ArrayList<FundingRequest> fundingRequests) {
        this.fundingRequests = fundingRequests;
    }

    public void add(FundingRequest newFundingRequest) {
        this.fundingRequests.add(newFundingRequest);
    }

    public ArrayList<FundingRequest> getFundingRequests() {
        return fundingRequests;
    }
}
```

The ArrayList holds `FundingRequest` type objects, which is actually an Abstract object with two concrete sub-classes `FixedFundingRequest`, `TrackerFundngRequest` inheriting from it. These two sub-class objects are both loaded into the ArrayList, as I need a convenient storage for all `FundingRequest` objects.

However, I also need to access the sub-class objects separately, and - for example, there might be a case where it would be highly inefficient to loop through the single ArrayList looking for `FixedFundingRequest` objects, if the vast majority are `TrackerFundingRequest` objects.

The solution I'm imagining would be to add code so that the `FundingRequestData` class has not one, but three ArrayList objects to provide more efficient searches when I'm looking for a particular child of the `FundingRequest` class:

```
public class FundingRequestData {
    private ArrayList<FundingRequest> fundingRequests;
    private ArrayList<FixedFundingRequest> fixedFundingRequests;
    private ArrayList<TrackerFundingRequest> trackerFundingRequests;

    private static FundingRequestData instance = new FundingRequestData();

    public static FundingRequestData getInstance() { return instance; }

    public FundingRequestData() {
        this.fundingRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        this.fixedFundingRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        this.trackerFundingRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public FundingRequestData(ArrayList<FundingRequest> fundingRequests) {
        // loop through objects & use add methods to initialise arrays
    }

    public void add(FixedFundingRequest newFundingRequest) {
        this.fundingRequests.add(newFundingRequest);
        this.fixedFundingRequests.add(newFundingRequest);
    }

    public void add(TrackerFundingRequest newFundingRequest) {
        this.fundingRequests.add(newFundingRequest);
        this.trackerFundingRequests.add(newFundingRequest);
    }

    public ArrayList<FundingRequest> getFundingRequests() {
        return fundingRequests;
    }

    public ArrayList<FixedFundingRequest> getFixedFundingRequests() {
        return fixedFundingRequests;
    }

    public ArrayList<TrackerFundingRequest> getTrackerFundingRequests() {
        return trackerFundingRequests;
    }
}
```

From what I've described (and I can provide more info if this is insufficient), can anyone help me to understand the pitfalls to this design, and what might be better? I don't know if this kind of design is necessarily frowned upon, but it doesn't seem right. Then again - without implementing more and more classes, I don't know of any alternative.

Comment: *"The ArrayList holds FundingRequest objects, which is actually an Abstract object "* ... What is an abstract object?  An abstract class can define a type, but you can't actually ever have an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: @scottb Yes - of course. I'll correct it to read 'The ArrayList holds FundingRequest type objects', right?

Comment: Probably you want to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in declarations and function signature

Comment: I would vote for keeping only `fixedFundingRequests` `trackerFundingRequests` and remove reference to `fundingRequests` from class if you really need access to sub classes. You can construct it anyways

Comment: @Archit And that way, having two Lists rather than three within the data model class? Unfortunately I need the functionality of having the fundingRequests list too. I'm just unsure of whether this needs to be split into multiple classes, or if there is an inherent problem with my design.

Comment: @jpanton yes, since you can construct the third anyways. Only thing you would only miss out on is order of insertion of `fundingRequests`